# Query API with Array Parameters in React

Tags: reactjs, api

My params in React is an array, checkedItems:['location1', 'location2']. When it calls my API, the URL looks like this

```
/api/search?checkedItems[]=location1&checkedItems[]=location2
```

instead of

```
/api/search?checkedItems=['location1','location2']
```

My API application is expecting to query a comma delimited array parameter:

```
  public List<myclass> Get( string checkedItems = null)
    {
      IQueryable<myclass> qry = (from a in db.myclass
                       select a);

        if (checkedItems != null)
        {


            string[] items = checkedItems.Split(',');
            foreach (var item in items)
            {

                {
                    qry = qry.Where(a => items.Contains(a.mycolumn));

                }

            }
           }

     return qry.ToList();
       }
```

How do I change the react code or change API code? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `'/api/search?checkedItems=['location1','location2']'`, separate the array field with commas, like so `'/api/search?checkedItems=location1,location2'`

To do this,

```
let checkedItems = ['location1', 'location2']
// using template literals
let url = `/api/search?checkedItems=${checkedItems.join(',')}`
```

Then on the backend simply get the query param `checkedItems` and split it `checkedItems.split(',')` to get the array.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on your backend technology, but *a lot* of API libs/framework automatically transform parameters to array for you.

Keep in mind that having an URL like `/api/search?checkedItems=location1&checkedItems=location2` (so: same parameter multiple times) is a perfectly valid URI.

I can't say if this is your case or not.